# Android Animation on multiple images in RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have to download an `image`, `split` it in 9 equal parts and show them in `animated form` in an `imageview`.
I have achieved this when I `download` single `image` and `animate` it in `Activity`, but when I do same in `Recycler view`(multiple items), the `images` get repeated on `scrolling`, image` positions are changed.

Note : I am using `Volley` to download image, and perform splitting in `async task`.

Below is the code for RecyclerView adapter.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>{

private Context mContext;
private List<ObjectClass> arrayListData;
private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
private int mBackground;

public Adapter(Context mContext, List<ObjectClass> arrayListData) {
    mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground,    mTypedValue, true);
    mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.arrayListData = arrayListData;
}

// View Holder class
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View convertView;
    NetworkImageView ivFeedImage;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        convertView = view;
        ivFeedImage = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFeedImage);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.lvadapter, parent, false);
    view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

final ObjectClass data = arrayListData.get(position);

            ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(data.getUrl(), new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    SplitImage task = new SplitImage(); // to split image in 9 equal parts and animate it one imageView
                    task.execute(bitmap, holder.ivFeedImage);
                }
            }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                    holder.ivFeedImage.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(imageRequest);

}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListData == null ? 0 : arrayListData.size();
}

class SplitImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    //doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) params[0];
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) params[1];
            if(bitmap != null){
                final ArrayList<Bitmap> arrImages = splitImage(bitmap); // method for splitting the image into 9 parts
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        animateImage(imageView, arrImages, 0, true); // method for applying animation to arralist of images
                    }
                });

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you are using? Proably you need some flag inside model and if condition in your viewholder to indicate if image was already animated.

Comment: @JakubSzczygieł Please check the edit.Thanks